# Serving audio files from Web Api Project in IIS7.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an audio file I'm trying to serve from a directory within a ASP.NET MVC Web Api Project. For some reason the file refuses to play in Safari or mobile browsers. I can use every other browser to play this file.

What's driving me nuts is that if I just create a Virtual Directory and add the file there then navigate to it like /NewSite/song.m4a it will play fine in safari and mobile.

I thought maybe my web.config was screwing something up so I tried creating another Web Api project hosted in IIS and I still cannot play the audio file in Safari or mobile browsers in the new app.

I've done everything I can think of. I have the mime type added to my site. Other browsers like firefox and chrome play the file fine.

Has anyone seen this behavior? I'm going insane here.

Answer (score 2):

I seriously wasted an entire day on this.

My IIS server is using a self signed cert. I was trying to load the audio file through https.

apparently every other browser is cool with this except Safari and mobile browsers.

I changed the src attribute to be http instead of https and safari started working as well as my iOS simulator.